# Rails 3 js blocks: render a partial with a jquery snippet or render snippet as text?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on my first 'real' (as opposed to playing around) rails 3 project after using rails 1&2 for the last four years.  In the destroy action's js block i want to do something typical: remove the div containing the deleted resource on the page.

I can't decide whether it's better to render out a destroy.js.erb file like so: (the resource in question is a 'note' and the method .dom_id just returns a string like "note_#{note.id}".)

Approach A: render a js view file

```
#in controller
  format.js

#in views/notes/destroy.js.erb
$('#<%= @note.dom_id %>').remove();
```

This has the advantage of keeping the controller totally clean and standard.

Approach B: put the js in the controller:

```
#in controller
format.js { render :text => "$('##{@note.dom_id}').remove()" }
```

This has the advantage of enabling the person looking at the controller code to instantly see what's going on, without going hunting for a view file with one line of code in it.  On the other hand, it breaks MVC.

What do you think?  Which is more 'proper', 'standard', etc?  Is there a third (fourth, fifth) way that's even better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to follow *Approach A*, even though you may only have a few lines worth of code. The reason is that you may have a teammate that sees *Approach B* and decides that when you need to add more JavaScript to the render, doing it inline is the correct approach. Inlining JavaScript can (according to what I've read) be used for very simple one one-liners, but even then it's not recommended.

If you want to avoid having to look around for the proper JS view file, you can always render a specific file rather than following the "file --> controller action" naming convention. That way the exact js.erb file you're using is clear in your controller.

Comment: That all seems sensible, thanks @McStretch. I was kind of leaning in that direction.

Comment: No problem @Max. I always have the same misgivings, especially for one-liners. I guess another reason to always go for *Approach A* is that you're probably going to have some js.erbs that do contain a lot of JavaScript (which you wouldn't inline), so you might as well keep it consistent and always go the file route. That would make future decisions easy because you always go down one route.